# How do you convert RDD[Array[Byte]] into Array[Byte]

Tags: arrays, scala, rdd

I am a bit stuck trying to convert `RDD[Array[Byte]]` into `Array[Byte]`. I have the following  where I am first extracting the `RDD[Array[Byte]]` from a previously defined tuple in the form of `RDD(String, Array[Byte])`:

```
val extractArrayFromRDD: RDD[Array[Byte]] = rdd.map(t => t._2)
```

I then can really only get the first element of the array, as follows:

```
val rddToBytes: Array[Byte] = extractArrayFromRDD.first()
```

However, I indeed need to be returned with the entire Array, but I do not seem to find a way to do it. Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood you correctly, but if you want to collect your RDD you can obtain it as an `Array` using

```
rdd.collect()
```

which should return an `Array[Array[Byte]]`. And if you want the arrays combined into an `Array[Byte]`, you can use `flatten()` or whatever suits your needs.

Comment: thank you for your comment. Yeah I was not sure how to move from Array[Array[Byte]] to the desiderd data structure Array[Byte]. I am indeed fairly new to RDD manipulation and Scala programming in general.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Notice however the implications of collecting: You're losing the benefits of distribution of the data, and moreover you have to make sure there is not too much data 
in the RDD to be collected to an array on the master. Ae a consequence, you should generally perform as much of the work as possible *before* collecting.